# Win8.1 Share secured with LiveID

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows, shared-folders

I'm very new to the whole Ubuntu thing, so please bear with :)

I have a password protected network share on a Windows 8.1 machine (secured with a Microsoft LiveID) that I need to access from Ubuntu.

I've looked around and seen people suggesting switching the Win 8 machine to a local login rather than Live login, but that isn't an option in this context - is there *any* way I can get Ubuntu to authenticate on that share?

Much obliged! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to do that, but I can suggest you Samba. You can do more research at the following website:

http://www.samba.org/